# Why doesn't right-click work on my desktop?

Tags: lightdm, nautilus-elementary

I installed elementary OS and e17 on my Ubuntu 12.04 from ppas. After logout and login, right click on desktop is not working in gnome and unity but working in file manger.When I login into Pantheon session, I don't find an option to open Home folder and my login display manager theme is also changed.I want to get back to default Ubuntu login theme.Can i change the login theme with simple-lightdm manager. I dont want to mess up my system.Please hemp me how to fix these.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling the elementary and e17 software and rebooting?

Comment: done that too..

Comment: Have you considered reinstalling nautilus.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to the Software Center, type Advanced Settings in search, and install the Advanced Settings (Gnome Tweak) tool.

[image: Gnome Tweak]

- Click on the launcher (top left), type `advanced` and run the Advanced Settings tool. Under Desktop, set the first item "Have file manager handle the desktop" to **ON**. If it is ON, turn off then on again.

[image: adv settings]

- That should hopefully fix the right-click issue.

Comment: whoa.. that was easy as cake

Comment: For users of other (later?) versions of Ubuntu (confirmed for 16.04), the Gnome Tweak tool may not have that option ("Have file manager handle the desktop"). They may have a similar one (set "Icons on Desktop" to "On"). Regardless of the GUI, the following command seems to do the trick: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true`.

Comment: Is there a permanent fix for this? Every time I reboot I have to do this. And it's getting annoying

Answer (score 3):

That happens when the desktop icons are disabled. You can use the permanent fix of going to `dconf-editor`, **org > gnome > desktop > background** and click **show desktop icons**, then reboot and it's solved.

I hate the desktop icons, but unity disables other features if this is removed.

Answer (score 2):

please try the following to repair the rightclick-behaviour of the desktop:

1. Install gconf-editor and open it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gconf-editor && gconf-editor
   ```
2. Go to apps > nautilus > preferences
3. Check whether the tick at the 'show desktop' entry is set.
4. If not, activate this item.
5. Restart the machine or log out and log in back.

These steps should clear your problem with the desktop :)

Comment: no such option called preferences

Answer (score 2):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. Here is how I rectified this problem (actually discovered something)

1. Install GNOME Tweak
2. Run it (obviously)
3. Click on the **Keyboard and mouse** Tab
4. There is an option for *workstation emulation*
5. You can select your profile and live happily ever after.

Comment: A reboot is needed before this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The same situation happened to me after I did an upgrade of the system to Ubuntu 18.04. Here's my solution:

You have to make sure that you have installed **Gnome Tweaks**, after that, go to the section **Keyboard & Mouse**, at the bottom there are three options, make sure that the option **Area** is selected.

[image: Options of Keyboard & Mouse section in Tweaks]