# Ubuntu-desktop (file, edit, help, etc...) missing from panel after unity --reset

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, panel, menu-bar

After running `unity --reset` to fix a Compiz plug-ins problem, the dropdown menus (file, edit, help, etc...) that normally appear on the left end of the menu bar when the desktop is in focus are missing.

Any suggestions as to how I can correct this? I am running version 12.04.

Comment: You have 2 questions here. As this is a Q & A site it would be preferable to address them separately as others that are experiencing one of these issues are unlikely to be experiencing the other. Please [edit] this question to address the one and open a new question for the other. This helps us to be more efficient and allows us to help as many people as possible. Thank you for your understanding!

Comment: Your first question already has a good answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142772/ubuntu-12-04-upgrade-top-side-bar-missing/142813#142813)

Comment: I removed the desktop background question, though it also occurred at the same time as my other problem, so I thought they may be related and mentioning both of them might help in finding in answer. But the post you mention does not answer my first question. That was an issue I had in the past (panel and launcher missing). After running unity --reset as the answer suggests, the launcher and panel returned but the Ubuntu Desktop menu is missing from the panel. I still want to fix this and that's what this question is about. I have not found an existing answer on the site which helps.

Comment: "Desktop menu"? Are you talkin about the menu that appears when you have the Desktop folder open in the File manager?

Comment: No, it is a menu that appeared when all windows were closed and I clicked somewhere on the desktop. It still appears in the other account on my computer. I'll get a screen shot and post it to show what I mean.

Comment: Oh, The right-click menu perhaps? The one with New Folder, New Document, Change Background and etc.?

Comment: If everything works as advertised on the other account you likely have a corrupt profile.

Comment: Yes, I thought maybe it was a profile problem, but wasn't sure and I still don't know how to fix it. I don't mean the right click menu at all. I tried to upload a screenshot but found I don't have the reputation required. Can you look at the image here? http://imgur.com/Yg0uhtm

Comment: That menu doesn't appear without an application running. To determine which one, click Help and then About.

Comment: No, it does. It was. The image shows that it does. When all windows are minimized or closed and the desktop is in focus, a menu should appear as shown in the image. How do I get this Ubuntu Desktop menu back?

Comment: I'll go back into the other account again and look at Help and About to see if it says what application this is.

Comment: A minimized window is still running. I'm sorry for any confusion you may be experiencing.

Comment: I checked the Help dropdown menu in the other account, and there was no About item, just Ubuntu Help. I might have to give up. I can't find out anywhere what application Ubuntu Desktop might be or how to start it again.

Comment: Don't give up.  There are alternatives. You could create a new user profile and copy your data over to it for instance. Since you have an account that's working properly it would seem the issue is related to your profile on this one account.

Comment: Thanks, I was considering creating a new account if I could find no other solutions. I'll try what you suggest below and see if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt`

Reboot

If that doesn't work try

`sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt`

reboot

`sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt`

reboot

Sources:

https://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/disable-the-global-menu-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Testing

Comment: No, I'm sorry. This solution had no effect. Could it be there is some setting somewhere that will enable the menu I'm missing rather than installing or reinstalling software?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem! After you mentioned the right click menu I found that that was missing as well so I did a search and found this solution:

[Why doesn't right-click work on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142247/why-doesnt-right-click-work-on-my-desktop)

I toggled "Have file manager handle the desktop" as the post describes and the Ubuntu Desktop menu is back. Thanks for your help!